# Can Microsoft's Excel arrays deal with "user defined" types?

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array, types, vba

It is easy creating an array in MS Excel VBA, be it 1-dimensional or multi-dimensional, and set it to type Integer or String. Is it possible to do complex arrays however along these lines (this is not true code but represents what I mean):

`1 to 100 rows
    1 to 100 columns
      f_Depth: Float
      1 to 4 points
        l_X: Long
        l_Y: Long`

The Excel integer-only (or float-only or whatever you choose) makes it very difficult to work with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "complex array" do you mean array of mixed type? If so, you can use `Collection` which accepts objects of any type:

```
Dim Data As New Collection
Data.Add (1)
Data.Add ("Hello world")
Data.Add (3.14)
```

Comment: I do mean an array of mixed type. Will it accept arrays as objects please?